# Android transaction manager mactive add sequence

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I am doing a nested fragment and manage by getChildFragmentManager() and I found problem of the sequence to add fragment into mactive list is reversed and cause problem when display

```
FragmentManager m = parentFragment.getChildFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction t = m.beginTransaction();
    for(int i=0; i < 5; i++){
        t.add(Fragment.instantiate(context, "com.app.user.Fragment"), "");
    }
t.commitAllowingStateLoss();
m.executePendingTransactions();

t = m.beginTransaction();
for (Fragment f : m.getFragments()){
    t.remove(f);
}
t.commitAllowingStateLoss();
m.executePendingTransactions();
```

In this case, I found the mactive arraylist still allocated 5 spaces, if I add other fragment again, it will be added to the mactive[4] down to mactive[0], then allocate new space, mactive[5], mactive[6] ...... Hence the sequence is out of control.

Anyone face this before ? Is it a bug in android ? Any solution about this ?
Thanks

Comment: Why is this a problem?

Comment: I think the system use the sequence of mactive to create view.
For example, I want to retrieve sorted data, put in fragment and display in order. This problem make the program display in wrong order